# unable to select the wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress, config

Unable to select the wordpress database.[image]

I am using WAMP server in windows 7 OS

while configuring the wordpress i am getting this kind of error

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not creating the database.You need to create database schema first manually.  First Create database in Phpmyadmin. And give that name in your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the database name you have given in wp-config.php is correct. Check if the database user name and password is correct. Also check if the user has the privilege to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

Some times the problem appears when you have everything right there!!

So if you make sure you have created a database, giving the database name correctly while installing and you still are seeing the error, then:

```
1>> go to the root of your server

2>> Edit the file wp-config.php, set everything there manually, its that easy ;)
```

That should work for you!!